# How to control new variables' names after tidyr's spread?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe with panel structure: 2 observations for each unit from two years:

```r
library(tidyr)
mydf <- data.frame(
    id = rep(1:3, rep(2,3)), 
    year = rep(c(2012, 2013), 3), 
    value = runif(6)
)
mydf
#  id year      value
#1  1 2012 0.09668064
#2  1 2013 0.62739399
#3  2 2012 0.45618433
#4  2 2013 0.60347152
#5  3 2012 0.84537624
#6  3 2013 0.33466030
```

I would like to reshape this data to wide format which can be done easily with `tidyr::spread`. However, as the values of the `year` variable are numbers, the names of my new variables become numbers as well which makes its further use harder.

```r
spread(mydf, year, value)
#  id       2012      2013
#1  1 0.09668064 0.6273940
#2  2 0.45618433 0.6034715
#3  3 0.84537624 0.3346603
```

I know I can easily rename the columns. However, if I would like to reshape within a chain with other operations, it becomes inconvenient. E.g. the following line obviously does not make sense.

```r
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% spread(year, value) %>% filter(2012 > 0.5)
```

The following works but is not that concise:

```r
tmp <- spread(mydf, year, value)
names(tmp) <- c("id", "y2012", "y2013")
filter(tmp, y2012 > 0.5)
```

Any idea how I can change the new variable names within `spread`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know some years has passed since this question was originally asked, but for posterity I want to also highlight the `sep` argument of `spread`. When not `NULL`, it will be used as separator between the key name and values:

```
mydf %>% 
 spread(key = year, value = value, sep = "")
#  id   year2012  year2013
#1  1 0.15608322 0.6886531
#2  2 0.04598124 0.0792947
#3  3 0.16835445 0.1744542
```

This is not exactly as wanted in the question, but sufficient for my purposes. See `?spread`.

**Update with tidyr 1.0.0**: tidyr 1.0.0 have now introduced `pivot_wider` (and `pivot_longer`) which allows for more control in this respect with the arguments `names_sep` and `names_prefix`. So now the call would be:

```
mydf %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = value,
              names_prefix = "year")
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#        id year2012 year2013
#     <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#   1     1    0.347    0.388
#   2     2    0.565    0.924
#   3     3    0.406    0.296
```

To get exactly what was originally wanted (prefixing "y" only) you can of course now get that directly by simply having `names_prefix = "y"`.

The `names_sep` is used in case you gather over multiple columns as demonstrated below where I have added quarters to the data:

```
# Add quarters to data
mydf2 <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:3, each = 8), 
  year = rep(rep(c(2012, 2013), each = 4), 3), 
  quarter  = rep(c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"), 3),
  value = runif(24)
)
head(mydf2)
# id year quarter     value
# 1  1 2012      Q1 0.8651470
# 2  1 2012      Q2 0.3944423
# 3  1 2012      Q3 0.4580580
# 4  1 2012      Q4 0.2902604
# 5  1 2013      Q1 0.4751588
# 6  1 2013      Q2 0.6851755

mydf2 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(year, quarter), values_from = value,
              names_sep = "_", names_prefix = "y")
# # A tibble: 3 x 9
#      id  y2012_Q1  y2012_Q2  y2012_Q3  y2012_Q4  y2013_Q1  y2013_Q2  y2013_Q3  y2013_Q4 
#   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1     0.865     0.394     0.458    0.290      0.475     0.685     0.213     0.920
# 2     2     0.566     0.614     0.509    0.0515     0.974     0.916     0.681     0.509
# 3     3     0.968     0.615     0.670    0.748      0.723     0.996     0.247     0.449
```

Comment: this is exactly what is wanted :) "change the new variable names within `spread`"

Answer (score 14):

You can use `backticks` for column names starting with numbers and `filter` should work as expected

```
  mydf %>%
      spread(year, value) %>%
      filter(`2012` > 0.5)
  #  id      2012      2013
  #1  3 0.8453762 0.3346603
```

Or another option would be using `unite` to join two columns to a single columnn after creating a second column 'year1' with string 'y'.

```
  mydf %>%
     mutate(year1='y') %>%
     unite(yearN, year1, year) %>%
     spread(yearN, value) %>%
     filter(y_2012 > 0.5)
 #   id    y_2012    y_2013
 #1  3 0.8453762 0.3346603
```

Even we can change the 'year' column within `mutate` by using `paste`

```
 mydf %>%
     mutate(year=paste('y', year, sep="_")) %>%
     spread(year, value) %>%
     filter(y_2012 > 0.5)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the `setNames()` function as the next thing in the pipe:

```
mydf %>%
    spread(mydf, year, value) %>%
    setNames( c("id", "y2012", "y2013") ) %>%
    filter(y2012 > 0.5)
```

The only problem using setNames is that you have to know exactly what your columns will be when you `spread()` them. Most of the time, that's not a problem, particularly if you're working semi-interactively.

But if you're missing a key/value pair in your original data, there's a chance it won't show up as a column, and you can end up naming your columns incorrectly without even knowing it. Granted, `setNames()` will throw an error if the number of names doesn't match the number of columns, so you've got a bit of error checking built in.

Still, the convenience of using `setNames()` has outweighed the risk more often than not for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using `spread()`'s successor `pivot_wider()` we can give a prefix to the created columns :

```r
library(tidyr)
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:3, rep(2,3)), 
  year = rep(c(2012, 2013), 3), 
  value = runif(6)
)

pivot_wider(mydf, names_from = "year", values_from = "value", names_prefix = "y")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id y2012 y2013
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 0.266 0.372
#> 2     2 0.573 0.908
#> 3     3 0.202 0.898
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

rename() in dplyr should do the trick

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  spread(year,value)%>%
  rename(y2012 = '2012',y2013 = '2013')%>%
  filter(y2012>0.5)
```

Comment: conceptually, it is the same as @crazybilly's answer